# Limit of sequences? question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Ok, so I'm trying to find the limit of these two sequences when $n \to \infty$;

i) $\frac{3^{n+2}}{5^n}$

ii) $n\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Yeah ok I realized my idea on the first one would have worked but I made a critical mistake by not setting y = $\frac{3^{n+2}}{5^n}$ so if I did that it would have worked and go to 0 :) on the second question I have no idea
thanks for tips and solutions :)

Comment: Regarding ii), do you know that $\;\;\frac{1}{x}\cdot \sin {x} \rightarrow 1\;$ when $\;x \rightarrow 0?$

Comment: well I guess now, but Idk how this can help me solve the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the expression in this form

$$\frac{3^{n+2}}{5^n}=3^2\times\left(\frac35\right)^n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\;\text{because}\; 0\le\frac35<1$$

For the second limit remember that
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: sorry, if the answer is 0 then yes, if no, then no

Comment: that is from just using l hopital rule or wahtever I think and derivative it and cos(0)=1 so I get 1* -1/n^2 which 1 divided a very large number whihc is 0? cuz if I just plug in values into the original version I get inf*0 +

Comment: Yes for the second limit you can use the L'Hôpital rule to get the limit $1$ and to answer your question just take $x=\frac1n$.

Comment: YES! and that will go to 0 as n->infinity!

Comment: Nice answer and follow-up!